# Having /Boot Partition trouble

Tags: boot

I'm trying to switch from Ubuntu to Windows 7, mainly due to compatibility issues. I'm having trouble doing so however.

Whenever I start up my computer it says, I have "0 bytes" left in my /boot partition. This is hindering me from either going to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS or installing Windows.